# Chaining OpenID tokens

Tags: authentication, openid

I'm working in microservices environment, where each service authenticates using `OpenID Connect` to an authentication service (local IdP), based on Users I keep locally on my Database.

Now, I want these services to be able to authenticate using `Azure`, `Google`, etc.

Can (and should) I modify my authentication service to allow redirection to another `IdP`, and replace or chain the token to my proprietary token for my services?
Is there a simpler way?

How can I allow users to login both using name / password OR external IdP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing some research on the topic by myself as well and from what I've found until now, it seems that there is a urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange grant type that should allow exchanging external idp token to an internal one as described in [some spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-19).

It should be supported as part of the openid connect /token endpoint so as long as the local idp supports it, I guess that this should be the best practice to achieve what you are looking for.

I'm currently looking into [mitreid-connect](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server) idp implementation as local idp and some of my requirements is to also allow SSO with third parties while being able to issue a local token from the external user identity.

Will update as it goes...

Answer (score 0):

If you manage all the SP (your microservices) it's definitely easier to implement it on your common IDP.

But if the SP are external ones (like existing services you just installed) and they already implements the public IDP you want to use, it was be a bit harder to pass through your current IDP without problem.

---

I'm guessing you are in the first case (you made all your SP) so I will elaborate it:

When your current IDP will authenticate user on others public IDP, it will get some information (email, name, etc.) and you can normalize those in your answer, to be sure your SP are completely agnostic of which original IDP was used. It will be better for you if the future to debug this setup. And of course to add a new public IDP...

But if you need to use some specific call to original IDP, (let says Youtube API for example) you could have a agnostic API on your common IDP which will forward to the appropriate proprietary API of original IDP, or deny the request if the IDP does not have a video system.

Or you could give original token to your SP, in a custom field or scope of your oidc token, so for example an SP dedicated to video could directly call Youtube API with the google user token.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a similar setup for my company. I would like to share the overall structure to give an idea about our solution. Hope it helps:

Our authentication server is an [node express](https://expressjs.com/) server with following properties:

- Hosts static login screens to allow authentication against local database via email + password, as well as provides links to authenticate with external OAuth2 providers.
- Both local and external authentication requests are forwarded to [Passport.js Authentication strategies](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/)
- After successful login, both local and external Passport.js strategies respond to a callback. Upon this response, a session object is created via [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) and a cookie is sent.
- At this point, cookies can be used to exchange JWT's, so that authentication against stateless API's can be possible with Bearer Access Tokens.